# Teradata Unicode TPT enabled but not working, how do you get UnicodePassThrough = 'ON' to work?

Tags: teradata

Hi I have tried to script my tpt to enable it to  insert emoji's into a table. However it is not inserting it as expected, it is coming out as random characters ðŸ‘Œ ðŸ‘ ðŸ‘

Even though i have used the unicodepassthrough ='on'  and it is enabled as i can it in the logs. We are using TD version 16.20 and the column is set to Unicode also.

any help with this would be much appreciated?

Comment: Is the TPT session charset UTF8? To retrieve the data after loading the client also needs to switch to a Unicode session and `SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON;` and the font must support those characters, too (common issue on Windows).

Comment: how do i set the TPT session to charset UTF8 and also is the SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON; i thought that was applicable to BTEQ only not needing it in a TPT script ? i used this https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-Database-Administration/March-2019/Loading-and-Exporting-Data-Application-DBAs/Loading-Unicode-Data-with-Unicode-Pass-Through

Comment: even though i ran it with -e utf-8 it doesn't work either and not sure where to put the  SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON; in my script

Comment: `- e utf-8` indicates the *TPT script* is encoded in Unicode. For loading Unicode *data*  the TPT job must start with `USING CHARACTER SET UTF-8
DEFINE JOB ...`. And the `SET SESSION UNICODE ...` is set in the client to select the Unicode as-is.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth , i managed to get it working now.